# Real-time editable tables with Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

Apologies if this is a daft question, but is it possible to dynamically add/delete rows, and edit single cells of data in a Vuetify table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can achieve that. Please check vuetify docs here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#content-editing

To see it in action just click on Frozen Yogurt for example